# Multiple Inputs in a Dash application with many Tabs

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash, dashboard

I'm currently programming a Dash application and I'm facing a little problem:

In a callback, I want to use 2 inputs and 2 outputs but there's a tiny problem, both inputs are not in the same tab. I will show you my callback and the application thus you will understand my problem way better:

The callback:

```
@app.callback(
    [Output("kpi-viewer-tab","children"),Output("export-alert","is_open")],
    Input("start-calculations-button","n_clicks"),
    Input("dl-button","n_clicks"),
    [State("rack-boolean-switch","on"),
     State("bank-boolean-switch","on"),
     State("project-name","value"),
     State("name","value"),
     State("surname","value"),
     State("html-startdate-picker","value"),
     State("html-enddate-picker","value")]
    )

def viewer_tab (click_calcul,dl_click,on_r,on_b, project_name, user_name, surname, start_dt, end_dt):
    type_request = ""
    files = []
    name = "None"
    kpi_results = dict
    StartDay = pd.Timestamp("2023-04-14T12", tz='utc')
    EndDay = pd.Timestamp("2023-04-28T12", tz='utc')
    dt_start = [StartDay + datetime.timedelta(days = 1*dayIdx) for dayIdx in range(1)]
    dt_end = [EndDay + datetime.timedelta(days = 1*dayIdx) for dayIdx in range(1)]
    tmp_idSite = "eccb5d99-f46a-4780-8853-2124b062f5ca"
    project = ""
    user = ""
    raw_data = {}
    plot_df = {}
    x_axis = []
    global calcul_in_progress
        
    if project_name is None:
        return dash.no_update
    
    if user_name is not None and surname is not None:
        surname = surname.upper()
        user_name = user_name.title()
        user = user_name+" "+surname
    
    if on_r:
        type_request = "RACK"
    elif on_b:
        type_request = "BANK"
    else:
        type_request = "RACK"
        
    for index in range (len(project_name)):
        if project_name[index] == "_":
            name = project_name[:index]
            break
    if name == "None":
        name = project_name
        
    project = name

    files = LSP.load_files(Mapping_path, TimeSeries_path, name)
    
    print(files)

    if dl_click > 0:
        E2P.export2pdf(raw_data, plot_df,x_axis,project,user,str(start_dt),str(end_dt))
        return True
    else:
        if click_calcul > 0:
            calcul_in_progress = 1
            kpi_results = RC.run_kpi_calculations(project, type_request, dt_start, dt_end, tmp_idSite, files, param_dict, kpi_calculations)
            calcul_in_progress = 0
            
            plot_df, raw_data, x_axis = RC.extract_data_from_dict(kpi_results)
            click_calcul = 0

            return TB.inside_viewer(user, plot_df, raw_data, x_axis)
        else :
            return dash.no_update
```

The application:
[Screenshot of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VQ1P.png)

The first output is used to change the content of the Tabs element. The second is the alert which tells the user that the PDF is created.

The first input is a button at the bottom of the "KPI Config" tab and the second input is the Export to PDF button which is at the top of the "KPI Viewer" tab.

The problem is that when I'm on the tab "KPI Config" the button isn't even recognized so I just can't use it as my application need to be on the "KPI Config" tab at its initialization. (I don't if this can help, but content of tabs are updated with callbacks as well)

Does someone have a clue to solve this?
I'm not sure to give enough information for you to help me so if you need anything, ask me I'll answer you

(P.S.: I know there's some errors and not optimized code in this callback, I'll correct it later)

I tried to build 2 different callbacks and it worked as I wanted but, I had to use 6 global variables because of the function E2P.export2pdf which needs a lot of parameters.

Comment: Can you please add the layout code? Or at least a minimal working example that covers your issue. Intuitively I would say that it's coming from your Tab implementation choice (see different methods in the [Tabs doc](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/tabs))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can organize each python dash file for each tab under a local subdirectory relative to where your `app.py` (or equivalent) main dash app file is, and simply use `import` statements to import all the local variables from the tabs into the main app file. *You should not* [need to] *use global variables.*

## A simple dash app with multiple tabs and a callback which has multiple inputs from multiple tabs

#### For example:

### Your file directory structure could look like:

```bash
.
|-- app.py
`-- tabs
    |-- kpi_config.py
    `-- kpi_viewer.py
```

In each tab file, define a list of components creating the layout structure for each tab and name it `children`.

E.g., in `kpi_config.py` (tab #1) I have:

```py
import dash

from dash import dcc, html

children = [
    html.Div(html.H1("Header Config"), id="header-1"),
    html.Div(
        [
            html.Div("Convert Temperature"),
            "Celsius",
            dcc.Input(id="celsius-1", value=0.0, type="number"),
            " = Fahrenheit",
            dcc.Input(id="fahrenheit-1", value=32.0, type="number",),
        ]
    ),
]
```

and in `kpi_viewer.py` (tab #2) I have:

```py
import dash

from dash import dcc, html

children = [
    html.Div(html.H1("Header Viewer"), id="header-2"),
    html.Div(
        [
            html.Div("Convert Temperature"),
            "Celsius",
            dcc.Input(id="celsius-2", value=0.0, type="number"),
            " = Fahrenheit",
            dcc.Input(id="fahrenheit-2", value=32.0, type="number",),
        ]
    ),
]
```

To demonstrate dynamic/reactive callback functionality, I put a simple celsius-fahrenheit bidirectional calculator into both tabs using `dash.dcc.Input` components. However, they must have unique ids. So, based on which tab the components were in, I correspondingly appended a "1" or "2" to the ids. So, whenever an input on *either* tab is altered, we want *both* calculators to change (in this somewhat arbitrary example to simulate having inputs from separate tabs trigger the same callback, which will be shown next).

### And then, in the main app file `app.py`:

As shown in the top directory, I have code such as:

```py
import dash
from dash import Dash, Input, Output, State, callback, dcc, html, ctx

import tabs
from tabs.kpi_config import children as kpi_config
from tabs.kpi_viewer import children as kpi_viewer


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# Use `dash.dcc.Tabs` per docs
tab_pages = [
    dcc.Tab(label="KPI Config", children=kpi_config),
    dcc.Tab(label="KPI Viewer", children=kpi_viewer),
]
children = html.Div([dcc.Tabs(id="tabs", children=tab_pages)])

app.layout = children


@callback(
    [
        Output("celsius-1", "value"),
        Output("fahrenheit-1", "value"),
        Output("celsius-2", "value"),
        Output("fahrenheit-2", "value"),
    ],
    [
        Input("celsius-1", "value"),
        Input("fahrenheit-1", "value"),
        Input("celsius-2", "value"),
        Input("fahrenheit-2", "value"),
    ],
)
def sync_input(
    celsius_config, fahrenheit_config, celsius_viewer, fahrenheit_viewer
):
    input_id = ctx.triggered[0]["prop_id"].split(".")[0]

    def convert_temperature(c, f):
        if input_id.startswith("celsius"):
            f = None if c is None else (float(c) * 9 / 5) + 32
        else:
            c = None if f is None else (float(f) - 32) * 5 / 9
        return c, f

    if input_id.endswith("1"):
        c, f = convert_temperature(celsius_config, fahrenheit_config)
    else:
        c, f = convert_temperature(celsius_viewer, fahrenheit_viewer)

    return c, f, c, f


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Which yields, e.g., the following app behavior:
[image: Video screenshots of demonstrated dash app example]
where you can see that changes in one tab automatically, reactively change the components in both tabs simultaneously (because the callback is triggered by inputs from the components in *either* tab).

When only working with a multi-*tab* app (vs. a multi-*page* (i.e., url) app [where things get a little more complicated]), you can still define all your callbacks in the same file where the `dash.app` is declared. Because we've imported the dash components by importing the children of both tab files and assigning those to `app.layout` (using `dash.dcc.Tabs` to collect together two `dash.dcc.Tab` components), dash takes care of the rest and all of component ids in both tab files are now in the namespace of all defined callbacks in the `app.py` file.